# State override with geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3.py, scam, eth-call

I'm working on a generalized sniping bot, which spots liquidity additions on uniswap v2.
I need to know if the token i want to buy is a scam or not, so i would need to do some checks using eth_call() and state override, but I don't really get how to do them.
For now i get the liquidity adding tx in the pending, which means i have 5-10 seconds to make my simulations by the time the tx is mined.
Here is what I'd like to do :

1. Check if my balance is still empty after a swap in (token for WETH)
2. Check if i can swap back (WETH for tokens) and the sell fees

For both of those checks, the program needs to assume that the tx that adds liquidity (which is still pending) has already been confirmed, can I include this in the state override ? If yes, how ?

For the swap back, I can't just simulate a fake balance, because my address could be added in a blacklist when I swap in. So for this check, the token contract has to assume that I already have bought some tokens.

Do you have an idea on how I could do that ?